# polymorphic form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to create an add comment form on a page, but it'll need to appear multiple times on the same page.

Here's my model. I'm using Mongoid 3.0, but I don't think that matters. The models are working correctly.

```
class Project
  include Mongoid::Document
  ...
  embeds_many :comments, :as => :commentable
  ...
end

class Suggestion
  include Mongoid::Document
  ...
  embeds_many :comments, :as => :commentable
  ...
end

class Comment
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :commentable, :polymorphic => true
  ...
end
```

I have these routes

```
suggestion_comments POST   /suggestions/:suggestion_id/comments(.:format) comments#create
project_comments POST   /projects/:project_id/comments(.:format)       comments#create
```

I'm calling the form via:

```
= render partial: "comments/new", locals: { :commentable => stream.project }
= render partial: "comments/new", locals: { :commentable => stream.suggestion }
```

How do I create the form_for? I tried this but it doesn't work. Also, since I need to display this on the page multiple times, having a CSS `id` that duplicates on the page will cause issues with the JavaScript on this page.

```
= form_for commentable.comments, remote: true do |f|
  %fieldset
    .control-group
      .controls
        = f.text_area :content, :required => true, :placeholder => "Add a comment...", :maxlength => "1000"
    .form-actions
      = f.submit "Post"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trying, I finally figured it out... Turns out to be quite simple:

```
= simple_form_for([commentable, Comment.new], :remote => true) do |f|
```